# Mapbox GL JS center map on click near the boarder

Tags: mapbox

The code below centers the map on a click, how could this code be edited it so it only centers the map if the click is near the boarders (say within 100px) of the map?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.26.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.26.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZnJlZWFjY291bnQxIiwiYSI6ImNpZmFqZm53NDJmNXhzbWx4dXM5bm1leDMifQ.MMgR4bJlNNVYrzCLA_NBeA';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', //stylesheet location
    center: [-74.50, 40], // starting position
    zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});

  map.on('click', function (e) {
  var coords = e.lngLat;
        map.flyTo({
        center: [coords.lng ,  coords.lat],
          speed: 0.1,
          curve:1});
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that needs this in the future, this is what I ended up doing

```
   map.on('click', function(e) {
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  var coords = e.lngLat;
  if (e.point.x < 100)
    map.easeTo({
      center: [coords.lng, coords.lat],
      speed: 0.05,
      curve: 0.1
    });
  else if (e.point.x > w - 100)
    map.easeTo({
      center: [coords.lng, coords.lat],
      speed: 0.05,
      curve: 0.1
    });
  else if (e.point.y > h - 100)
    map.easeTo({
      center: [coords.lng, coords.lat],
      speed: 0.05,
      curve: 0.1
    });
  else if (e.point.y < 100)
    map.easeTo({
      center: [coords.lng, coords.lat],
      speed: 0.05,
      curve: 0.1
    });
  else {}
});
```